# Supress all whitespace and new lines for custom FreeMarker directive

Tags: java, freemarker, removing-whitespace

I am implementing a few directives to render the content according to some custom markup. I want the Freemarker source to be readable so I want liberal use of whitespace and linebreaks in the body of the template in the template source but want to suppress all of them when I am actually rendering them. Example:

Consider the FreeMarker source for a table:

```
<@table args={"border": 1}>
 <@tr>
  <@td>table_data_with_no_line_breaks_r1c1</@td>
  <@td>table_data_with_no_line_breaks_r1c2</@td>
  <@td>table_data_with_no_line_breaks_r1c3</@td>
 </@tr>
 <@tr>
  <@td>table_data_with_no_line_breaks_r2c1</@td>
  <@td>table_data_with_no_line_breaks_r2c2</@td>
  <@td>table_data_with_no_line_breaks_r2c3</@td>
 </@tr>
</@table>
```

Each directive is implemented roughly as:

```
class Table implements TemplateDirectiveModel {
 public void exec(Environment env, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars, TemplateDirectiveBody body) {
  env.getOut().write("<custom_table>");
  body.render(env.getOut());
  env.getOut().write("</custom_table");
 }     
}
```

Similar implementations exists for the other directives. I want the actual output to be like (each row should be in a single line with no leading or trailing whitespace):

```
<custom_table>
<row><column>data</column><column>data</column></row>
<row><column>data</column><column>data</column></row>
</custom_table>
```

How do I achieve this? I can use the `<#t>` directive at the end of each line to trim the whitespace but that seems clumsy and the template authors can forget to put that in sometimes. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You should go through Freemarker's [White-space handling](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html)

One option is `White-space stripping`

> If this feature is enabled for a template, then it automatically ignores (i.e. does not print to the output) two kind of typical superfluous white-space:

For example inside [ftl](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_ftl.html#ref.directive.ftl)

> Tells information about the template for FreeMarker and for other tools, also helps programs to automatically detect if a text file is an FTL file. This directive, if present, must be the very first thing in the template. Any white-space before this directive will be ignored.

Set [strip_whitespace](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_ftl.html#ref.directive.ftl) parameter value to true

> strip_whitespace: This enables/disables white-space stripping.

Other option is Using `compress directive`

> As opposed to white-space stripping, this works directly on the generated output, not on the template. That is, it will investigate the printed output on the fly, and does not investigate the FTL program that creates the output. It aggressively removes indentations, empty lines and repeated spaces/tabs
>
> ```
> <#compress>
> ```

Comment: As I have already stated, I am looking for a solution that I can implement in the directive implementation. I do not want a solution where the template authors have to remember to specify the whitespace striping. This is error prone and the authors can forget to do it correctly.

Comment: @SwarangaSarma you can set freemarker with White space stripping by default using https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setWhitespaceStripping-boolean-

Comment: Can I apply it only for a certain set of directives? I don't want it to affect all directives or rest of the template

Comment: @SwarangaSarma Do you want to define different configuration per template group? can't you add flt directive in specific templates you need?

Comment: I do not control the template creation since they can be dynamically generated and are loaded from a separate store. I want to ensure that if the template contains the table or the row directive, then the line breaks and the white space is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker is not practical if you often need precise white-space control. But when generating HTML that's usually not a problem as the amount of white-space (1 versus more) is insignificant at most places in HTML. If the output has to be human readable, or the additional size is a problem, you should apply white-space removal or formatting in the `Writer` that you pass to FreeMarker.